# GCC fails to generate 32-bit code from a function with inline assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, att

I try to generate 32-bit code like this: 
gcc -S -m32 BMPTransformer.c -o BMPTransformer.s

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04. People with similar problems seem to have overcome their difficulties by installing libc6-dev-i386. It hadn't worked for me, though.

The compiler complains:

BMPTransformer.c:243:6: error: can’t find a register in class ‘GENERAL_REGS’ while reloading ‘asm’
BMPTransformer.c:243:6: error: ‘asm’ operand has impossible constraints

Code as is:

```
216 static void ASM_reverse_image(BMPImage *image)
217 {
218      asm (
219             "movl $0, %%eax\n"
220 
221             "cmpl %%eax, %1\n"
222             "jl end\n"
223 
224             "row:\n"
225                  "movl (%0, %%eax, 4), %%edx\n"
226                  "decl %1\n"
227                  "movl (%0, %1, 4), %%esi\n"
228                  "movl %%esi, (%0,%%eax, 4)\n"
229                  "incl %%eax\n"
230                  "movl %%edx, (%0, %1, 4)\n"
231                  "cmpl %%eax, %1\n"
232                  "jg row\n"
233 
234             "end:\n"
235 
236             : : "r"(image->pixel_data), "r"(image->header.height): "%eax", "%edx", "%esi"
237       );
238 }
```

The code that used the 64-bits a,b,c registers had worked perfectly. But I need a 32-bit version.

Comment: Nit: the clobber list misses both a `"memory"` and `"cc"` entry. Also, gcc itself will very likely create better-performing code for this job (from equivalent C sourcecode)

Comment: Thank you! I missed these two, because I'm not yet accustomed to AT&T syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The error usually signals that the compiler has run out of registers. From the small fragment you posted that should not be the case, and indeed it compiles fine for me. You are probably not telling some important detail.

Anyway, there is absolutely no reason to write this in inline asm in its current form. The compiler can easily generate better (and working) code. The initial comparison certainly should be in C.

Side note: when using gcc inline asm the general idea is to leave as many possibilities to the compiler as possible. For example you don't specifically need any of the registers, you could have used generic constraints.

Comment: the "important detail" is the fact the function is declared `static`. gcc will usually try to _inline_ those, at least within the same compilation unit (sourcefile), so it depends on the caller - not shown.

Comment: I ran it on the other machine and it compiled fine. I might have not noticed an error during installing packages needed to generate 32-bit code. You were right in the first place.

I haven't found anything about generic constraints. Could you be a little more elaborate on this one?

Is there a way to write the more efficient algorithm in asm?

Answer (score -1):

code it as plain C:

```
static void ASM_reverse_image(BMPImage *image)
{
    int *pixel_data = image->pixel_data;
    int tmp;
    size_t idx = 0, height = image->header.height;

    for (idx = 0; idx < height; idx++) {
        tmp = pixel_data[idx];
        pixel_data[idx] = pixel_data[height - idx];
        pixel_data[height - idx] = tmp;
    }
}
```

or, if you're using C++, just:

```
    for (idx = 0; idx < height; idx++)
        std::swap(pixel_data[idx], pixel_data[height - idx]);
```

**Edit:** For assembly exercise, this would do:

```
int tmp;

asm("row:
     mov (%0), %2
     xchg %2, (%0, %1, 4)
     lea 4(%0), %0
     dec %1
     jns row"
    : : "r"(image->pixel_data), "r"(image->header.height), "r"(tmp)
    : "memory", "cc");
```

but this isn't good code - largely because this is a "streaming" type of processing and should be done via the vector units.

It's always a good idea in gcc inline assembly to *avoid requesting specific registers*. Let the compiler choose instead. That might mean you'll have to declare one or more "pseudovariables" as assembly register operands (to get a "reg reservation").

Comment: My C-code looks exactly like this. As you may have guessed I'd needed the inline assembly version only for practice.

Comment: I understand the assembly code you've written, but I don't get why it's bad. Could you be a little more precise on this one?

Comment: The inline asm isn't just inefficient (`xchg` with a memory operand has an implicit `lock` prefix, so it's very slow), it's not even safe.  **The asm modifies registers holding input-only operands**.   You're right that it's better to let the compiler allocate registers for you, though.  Starting an asm block with a `mov` is almost always a bad plan.  (Unless it's part of a loop like here, or you need the original copy, too).